# Do I understand the "data flow" ib data-driven app for WP7 right?

Tags: database, entity-framework, windows-phone-7, wcf-ria-services, local-storage

it's last question, I guess. 
One more time - I need to:

1. Get some piece of data from server to client with WP7.
2. Change data on a client in offline mode.
3. Send and submit changes on server.

After digging the net - i got next:

On a server side I have:
Entity framework --> WCF RIA

On a client side I have:
WCF RIA proxy classes --> (???????)-->db sterling -->USER UI-->

-->(changing data)-->db sterling-->(????????)-->WCF RIA proxy classes

So, question is - can I: 
1. Can I DETACH WCF RIA proxy objects from context

1. Save (serialaze) it in sterling
2. Change it in USER UI
3. Save changes in sterling again
4. And then restore (deserialaze) changed objects from sterling
5. ATTACH restored objects to context and then - save changes in main database?

In other words - can I operate directly with WCF RIA proxy classes on client-side 
(store-->change-->restore), and don't create any "support and translating" classes on a client-side?

Thanks.

P.S. May be that scheme is too complex? For this kind of app, I mean.

Comment: Because it seems WCF RIA employs Entity, I'm not so sure using RIA would be the best route to go with wp7. But apparently it is possible. I think that you would be better off just using WCF instead.

Comment: I think that this scheme is too complex. Now I try to use "siaqodb + Sync FrameWork Provider". It would be much simplier, I think.

Comment: Arrrrrrrrgggghhhhhh, I spent TOO MUCH TIME to choose right techology!

Comment: Crap that looks pretty awesome. Thanks for the info, I've never heard of siaqodb until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the RiaServiceContrib project in CodePlex at: http://riaservicescontrib.codeplex.com/

This library gives you the tools you require to take entities offline, save them to Isolated Storage, load them back, change them, save them again, etc. and then eventually to resubmit them back to the service through the context when you are back online.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But now I see no barriers to use Sync Framework. It's really cool thing.